# How to get a hook during WordPress backend edition?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to control value of what use input in WordPress backend, so I need to make action after each field is edited / changed. I did a lot of research but only things I can found is after "saving/updating". I need to check if user is creating some errors and can't wait it's saved. Any idea?

I need a : hook / trigger / action / event
Where : backend (post)
When : a field is edited / a field is changed / selection is changed (could also work)

I'm using [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) but the question is general to any change in WordPress backend (admin part).

For a comparison I need the equivalent of a C# "onchange" event but for WordPress.

Comment: You sound like you are wanting to perform a front-end (UI) event on the backend/server?  That makes no sense.  You can do an onchange in javascript and make an ajax call to the server.

Comment: Hello Chris, 
I don't thinks we have the same vocabulary... No I'm not talking about frontend (public part of the site) I'm talking about UI of the Backend (admin). I don't think this is a "non" sense as almost all other CMS have a "hook" when you edit something. Did you have an code example about how to do it in the clean way for WordPress (would have been better to use WP API).

Comment: "UI of backend (admin)" is still a UI in the browser (frontend).  You can detect changes in javascript, but you must send data to the server on that event if you want to access a wordpress hook.  Wordpress is running on the server.  The way to do that without a submit of entire page is to use the ajax interface in wordpress.  The admin interface of wordpress isn't special, it's still just a web page.

Comment: Did you have a code example on how I can catch a ACF on edition or on change? with ajax or anything else... thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659975/wordpress-plugin-jquery-validation-and-ajax